# Image with 15 distinct colors, how to save into 15 distinct files by color?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I have a PNG image with 15 distinct colors, you could say just N distinct colors. Is there a command line application which can split this into 15 distinct files each by color and each only retaining that color?

I looked at g'mic and I think maybe gmic file.png -compose_channels

might be the right direction, but it doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: I tried this before. There seemed no function in OpenCV and any other library. I had to do pixel-by-pixel operation with OpenCV to generate binary image of specific color pixel value.

Comment: So which color do you want the "other" pixels to have for each respective distinctly colored files? Transparent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to create an image mask for each isolated color, then composite the mask between the original image & (assuming) a grayscale image.

```sh
for color in `convert logo: -colors 15 -format %c histogram:info:- | cut -b 28-33`
do 
  convert logo: -colors 15 -matte \
    \( -clone 0 -colorspace gray \) \
    \( -clone 0 -fuzz 10% -transparent "#$color" -alpha extract \) \
    -composite out_$color.png
done
```

[image: distinct colors]

#### Command-line Break Down

The `convert logo: -colors 15 -format %c histogram:info:-` command prints what the 15 colors would be. Example:

```
      9221: (  9, 11, 12) #090B0C srgb(9,11,12)
      5692: ( 34, 38,101) #222665 srgb(34,38,101)
     13936: ( 34, 61,145) #223D91 srgb(34,61,145)
       661: ( 63, 85,135) #3F5587 srgb(63,85,135)
      1595: ( 85, 86, 87) #555657 srgb(85,86,87)
      1107: ( 94, 57, 34) #5E3922 srgb(94,57,34)
       972: (121,130,118) #798276 srgb(121,130,118)
      3264: (155,156,159) #9B9C9F srgb(155,156,159)
       596: (199,176, 70) #C7B046 srgb(199,176,70)
      1381: (209, 98, 69) #D16245 srgb(209,98,69)
      2348: (215,189,184) #D7BDB8 srgb(215,189,184)
      2502: (244,229, 50) #F4E532 srgb(244,229,50)
      2419: (244,150,101) #F49665 srgb(244,150,101)
      3494: (252,  6,  6) #FC0606 srgb(252,6,6)
    258012: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF srgb(255,255,255)
```

The `cut -b 28-33` isolates the hex-color column. With an isolated color, `( -clone 0 -colorspace gray)` will copy the original image, and convert to black & white (replace this if B/W is not desired.) Finally, `( -clone 0 -fuzz 10% -transparent "#$color" -alpha extract )` cherry-picks the isolated color, and generates a mask.

### Edit

If you don't want any of the "other" colors, then apply -compose CopyOpacity for each isolated color.

```sh
for color in `convert logo: -colors 15 -format %c histogram:info:- | cut -b 28-33`
do 
  convert logo: -colors 15 -matte \
    \( -clone 0 -fuzz 10% -transparent "#$color" -alpha extract -negate \) \
    -compose CopyOpacity -composite out_$color.png
done
```

[image: Colors only]

#### Edit 2

As [Kurt Pfeifle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359307/kurt-pfeifle) point out, and in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27726112/438117), an existing image with 15 distinct colors can be simplified.

```sh
for color in "221F20" "434345" "4965A2" "4B92BF" "552D2A" "625E5A" "6F9563" "966963" "988E72" "A7A199" "AC3939" "C9B4A7" "C9C9B5" "DFC255" "E6E6E2"
do 
  convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xots0.png -matte \
    \( -clone 0 -fuzz 10% -transparent "#$color" -alpha extract -negate \) \
    -compose CopyOpacity -composite out_$color.png
done
```

A montage of outputted files would look like...

[image: Kurt Pfeifle example]

Comment: **+ 1** -- Hey, @emcconville: your answer is better than mine. It would be nice if you could modify it, using an image that has already 15 colors (bringing `wizard:` into the game will only confuse newbie users). You could use [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xots0.png)  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the feed back @KurtPfeifle! I originally used my avatar, but opted to use a friendly/simple example. I'll update my answer with your photo.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not post a sample picture, I'll have to create one for the purpose of demo-ing my procedure for this task.

The base picture is the following. It still has more than 15 colors, of course. It was published on Flickr by *[atramos](https://www.flickr.com/photos/atramos/)* under a CreativeCommons license **[here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/atramos/6819541499/sizes/l)**.

[image]

I used the following command to convert it to a PNG using only 15 colors:

```
convert 6819541499_aa4b1dc049_o_d.jpg -colors 15  15c.png
```

The resulting image has only 230 kBytes:

[image]

Now that we have a PNG with 15 colors, let's look at a potential procedure to extract 15 images which contain only the pixels with one of these unique colors, rendering the other pixels transparent.

1. Verify that there are really only 15 colors.
2. Identify the 15 color values.
3. Identify for each color 1 pixel using exactly that color.
4. Create an image that contains all pixels with identical colors as the one from step 3.

### Verify that there are really only 15 colors

Here is a command that lists the number of unique colors used in an image:

```
identify -format "%k\n" 15c.png
```

Running it, confirms that we have 15 colors only:

```
  15
```

### Identify the 15 color values

Here is a command that lists all of these colors by color value:

```
convert 15c.png -format "%c" histogram:info:-
```

The result is this table. The left-most column gives the number of pixel using the color specified in the other columns (where each column displays a different syntax for specifying the color):

```
 29035: ( 34, 31, 32) #221F20 srgb(34,31,32)
 12056: ( 67, 67, 69) #434345 srgb(67,67,69)
  4425: ( 73,101,162) #4965A2 srgb(73,101,162)
  2376: ( 75,146,191) #4B92BF srgb(75,146,191)
  6607: ( 85, 45, 42) #552D2A srgb(85,45,42)
  8306: ( 98, 94, 90) #625E5A srgb(98,94,90)
  3923: (111,149, 99) #6F9563 srgb(111,149,99)
  4212: (150,105, 99) #966963 srgb(150,105,99)
  4692: (152,142,114) #988E72 srgb(152,142,114)
  9836: (167,161,153) #A7A199 srgb(167,161,153)
  8832: (172, 57, 57) #AC3939 srgb(172,57,57)
  6471: (201,180,167) #C9B4A7 srgb(201,180,167)
  7080: (201,201,181) #C9C9B5 srgb(201,201,181)
  4614: (223,194, 85) #DFC255 srgb(223,194,85)
 14895: (230,230,226) #E6E6E2 srgb(230,230,226)
```

To produce a list containing only the `#xxyyzz` syntax, I run:

```
convert 15c.png -format "%c" histogram:info:- | cut -c 28-34
```

which gives me this list:

```
221F20 
434345 
4965A2 
4B92BF 
552D2A 
625E5A 
6F9563 
966963 
988E72 
A7A199 
AC3939 
C9B4A7 
C9C9B5 
DFC255 
E6E6E2
```

(The `cut` command is only available by default in Linux, Mac OS X or Unix. On Windows, you'd need a Cygwin environment or at some special command line utilities installed).

### Identify for each color 1 pixel using exactly that color

The following command would output each pixel's coordinate and the color associated with it:

```
convert 15c.png text:-
```

To show you how this would look like, let's limit it to the first five lines only:

```
convert 15c.png text:- | head -n 5

 # ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 640,199,255,srgb
 0,0: (167,161,153)  #A7A199  srgb(167,161,153)
 1,0: (167,161,153)  #A7A199  srgb(167,161,153)
 2,0: (167,161,153)  #A7A199  srgb(167,161,153)
 [...]
```

(The `head` command is only available by default in Linux, Mac OS X or Unix. On Windows, you'd need a Cygwin environment or at some special command line utilities installed).

Now the command to identify 1 pixel for each color:

```
for color in $(echo $(convert 15c.png -format "%c" histogram:info:-|cut -c 28-34)); do
   convert 15c.png text:- | grep $color | head -n 1; 
done
```

which returns the following list:

```
475,0: (34,31,32)    #221F20  srgb(34,31,32)
456,0: (67,67,69)    #434345  srgb(67,67,69)
 12,0: (73,101,162)  #4965A2  srgb(73,101,162)
 14,0: (75,146,191)  #4B92BF  srgb(75,146,191)
248,0: (85,45,42)    #552D2A  srgb(85,45,42)
213,0: (98,94,90)    #625E5A  srgb(98,94,90)
249,0: (111,149,99)  #6F9563  srgb(111,149,99)
241,0: (150,105,99)  #966963  srgb(150,105,99)
 13,0: (152,142,114) #988E72  srgb(152,142,114)
  0,0: (167,161,153) #A7A199  srgb(167,161,153)
146,0: (172,57,57)   #AC3939  srgb(172,57,57)
  3,0: (201,180,167) #C9B4A7  srgb(201,180,167)
 18,0: (201,201,181) #C9C9B5  srgb(201,201,181)
126,0: (223,194,85)  #DFC255  srgb(223,194,85)
 32,0: (230,230,226) #E6E6E2  srgb(230,230,226)
```

The first column in this list gives the pixels' coordinates.

### Create an image that contains all pixels with identical colors as the one from the previous step

A general command to replace colors in an image is this:

```
convert some.png -fill red -draw 'color 13,45 replace' out.png
```

This command defines the fill color as red. Then it looks at the color of the pixels with coordinates `12,45` and replaces that same color for **all** pixels in the image which are identical to the colors of pixel `12,45`.

So what we need to use here is the following approach:

1. Enable the alpha channel in the PNG for transparency.
2. Define the fill color as transparent.
3. Replace the ***14*** different colors the image with transparent pixels and keep only one color.
4. Repeat the previous step 15 times.

This command would do it for the first unique color:

```
convert                       \
   15c.png                    \
  -alpha on                   \
  -fill none                  \
  -draw 'color 456,0 replace' \
  -draw 'color  12,0 replace' \
  -draw 'color  14,0 replace' \
  -draw 'color 248,0 replace' \
  -draw 'color 213,0 replace' \
  -draw 'color 249,0 replace' \
  -draw 'color 241,0 replace' \
  -draw 'color  13,0 replace' \
  -draw 'color   0,0 replace' \
  -draw 'color 146,0 replace' \
  -draw 'color   3,0 replace' \
  -draw 'color  18,0 replace' \
  -draw 'color 126,0 replace' \
  -draw 'color  32,0 replace' \
   output-color1-pixel-475_0.png
```

The resulting image is this:

[image]

---

## Update:

Here are all 15 images as extracted from the self-created sample image:

[image: pixel 475,0]

[image: pixel 456,0]

[image: pixel 249,0]

[image: pixel 248,9]

[image: pixel 241,0]

[image: pixel 213,0]

[image: pixel 14,0]

[image: pixel 12,0]

[image: pixel 146,0]

[image: pixel 126,0]

[image: pixel 32,0]

[image: pixel 18,0]

[image: pixel 13,0]

[image: pixel 3,0]

[image: pixel 0,0]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes it is possible in OpenCV. Realistically you may want to look somewhere else to find someone that has already solved the problem.

If OpenCV is operational on your machine, and you are able to write a little code, then you should be able to do this one color at a time. I haven't done this before, but if you are interested in learning how to use OpenCV then this method should point you in the right direction.

1. Load your image into a Mat. We'll call this Mat "A".
2. If know the the BGR values for the your N distinct colors, it will be something like: Scalar(255,0,0) , then you can use inRange() to get a binary mask for the color you want. This will give you a 1 channel Mat, we'll call this "B".
3. Do matrix multiplication A*B or if that doesn't work a bitwise A&B. The result should be a black image with patches of only the color you want.